# Compress to fixed length

Tags: algorithm, compression

I am looking for an algorithm that could compress binary data, not to smallest size, but to specified size. For example, if I have uncompressed data that comes in various 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 ... KB sizes, I would specify "compress to 1 KB" and assuming the data could be compressed to .65, .74, .83 KB sizes, the algorithm would stop at 1 KB, and return this standard size, leaving some entropy in the data. I could not pinpoint an algorithm for that. Does one exist?

Comment: Use ZIP and pad with zeroes? ;)

Comment: Do you need lossless compression?

Comment: Yes ZIP and pad, but I wanted to avoid the padding.

Comment: Yes, lossless compression.

Comment: IIRC, you don't actively need to pad since the ZIP stream contains an explicit EOF marker (or equivalent).

Comment: More specifically, I am worried that if I ZIP and pad, I don't really control the amount of waste in my storage, i.e. the quality of the storage. Ideally, I would be able to tune that.

Comment: Waste?  Quality?  What in the world are you talking about?

Comment: Whatever you want to do, this seems the wrong approach.  Why don't you tell us more about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can ZIP and pad with zeroes but still in some case the data is highly random and even very efficient compression algorithms cannot compress the data because there is no correlation between data hence you dont get any compression at all so getting compression up to a specific size is not possible.

Comment: I happen to know the data I need to compress. I'm not doing this for random, arbitrary data. I know the data compresses in all cases, a lot actually. I got that extra domain knowledge, I'm not doing compressing arbitrary data. But I want to prioritize getting a standard size over getting the best possible size reduction.

Comment: @Frank So why not use padding to get it to required size.

Comment: Yes - it is a possibility - I could even skip compression entirely and just pad. But if I do that, I have too much variability in the size of the input data, and I would end up with a lot of padding space, which would be wasted space. I'd like each object to fit in a nice, predictable box, while waste as little as possible to padding. I know it sounds strange.

Comment: @Frank what do you mean by wasting the space because you are wasting space in any case if you want the size to higher than the compressed size ?

Comment: Yes - and no - because fitting in a standard box is number 1 priority, before size. Once the object fits in the box, you can stop compressing to save CPU cycles. But I guess you are right, there is some waste. The size of the standard box(es) can also be adjusted, and I happen to know the distribution of the input data sizes.

Comment: @Frank If you are worried with clock cycles then you can stop the algorithm when you think that remaining object is fitting uncompressed in the file. You need to add sentinel value to check if compression has ended at that point. Many algorithms compress character by character.

Comment: So, the objective is to eliminate the variability in the sizes of the data while doing some compression, but stopping the compression as soon as one of the standard sizes has been achieved.

Comment: Yes, basically I would need an algorithm that I can stop at any point and still get a valid output. I might still have to do a little bit of padding, and that would be ok, if I can keep that padding minimal.

Comment: @Frank what sort of data u have ?

Comment: The data consists in JSON strings produced by one of our systems, so we know a lot about those strings.

Answer (score 0):

*It is not possible.*

Proof: Some combination of data can't be losslessly compressed, so that case fails your need to meet a fixed size, assuming that size is smaller than the original data.

If you can accept lossy compression it is very possible and happens all the time for some video formats (fixed size container per unit of time; compression adjusts to maximize usage).

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "some combination of data can't be losslessly compressed" - in my specific, I know that the data can be compressed. Did you mean that in full generality, there are going to be cases where data can't be compressed?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.